# Get black value of color of text Illustrator Scripting VB

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, illustrator-scripting, vbscript

I am trying to determine the value of the black in each text item in an illustrator document. I have managed to successfully run the count words script and alter it to apply a tint and a new color to each bit of text. Now I need to alter the tint based on its existing black value. Here is my attempt so far.

```
Set appRef = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")

If (appRef.Documents.Count = 0) Then
    Set docRef = appRef.Documents.Add
Else
    Set docRef = appRef.ActiveDocument
End If

If (docRef.TextFrames.Count = 0) Then
    Set textArt = docRef.TextFrames.Add
    textArt.Position = Array(100, 425)
    textArt.Contents = "Illustrator Scripting"
    textArt.TextRange.CharacterAttributes.Size = 48
End If

spotName = "CreateSpotSwatch"

' Create CMYKColor
Set cmykColor = CreateObject("Illustrator.CMYKColor")
cmykColor.Cyan = 0
cmykColor.Magenta = 0
cmykColor.Yellow = 0
cmykColor.Black = 100

' Create Spot
Set Spot = docRef.Spots.Add
Spot.Color = cmykColor
Spot.ColorType = 2 ' aiSpot
Spot.Name = spotName

For Each textArt In docRef.TextFrames

    Set spotColor = CreateObject("Illustrator.SpotColor")
    Set textArtRange = textArt.TextRange

    Set color = textArtRange.CharacterAttributes.strokeColor.Black  
    spotColor.Tint = color ' This should be the value of the black
    spotColor.Spot = Spot

    textArtRange.CharacterAttributes.strokeColor = spotColor
Next
```

Also happy to do this in Java if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have worked it out, it was a matter of actually using the fill color I think.

`Set Color = textArtRange.CharacterAttributes.FillColor
spotColor.Tint = Color.Black`